# jquery get current selected value from multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select drop down where I use array sign in name like

```
<select name="services[]" id="service_id" multiple>
  <option value="4">four</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Now I need to get current (last) selected value from drop down on change event.

What I have tried so far is

```
var clicked = $('#service_id option:selected').last().val();
alert(clicked);
//also tried as
//$(this).closest('select').find('option').filter(':selected:last').val();
//and this is tried too
// $(this).val();
// this.value;
```

All these giving me wrong value when multi select.

**What I need**

If select `four` then next select `one` it should alert `1` (remember when multi selection).

If select `three` and then next select `four` then it should alert `4`

In brief ALWAYS need **Clicked option's** value even in multi select

** Not possible to remove array sign from name `services[]`

Comment: Can you explain this - If select three and then next select four then it should aler 4 - sentence ? Are you trying to read the previously selected value on change ?

Comment: What is wrong with: alert($('#service_id option:selected').val());

Comment: clicked option's value? like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbpatil1/jeg1rv0L/)

Comment: @Zorken17 and abpatil Please read requirement carefully. suggested solution is wrong

Comment: If you want the last clicked element, you need to save your `services[]` in an other variable, and compare the two variables on the `change` event

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way, but you could save the order of the options clicked, then get the last.

ie, against a `data` attribute on the select:-

```js
$('#service_id option').click(function() {
  var values = $(this).parent().data('values') || [];
  var index = values.indexOf(this.value);
  index >= 0 ? values.splice(index, 1) : values.push(this.value);
  $(this).parent().data('values', values);
});

$('#service_id').click(function() {
  var values = $(this).data('values');
  console.log(values);
  
  var last = values[values.length - 1];
  console.log('last:' + last);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="services[]" id="service_id" multiple>
  <option value="4">four</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo

```js
$(function(){
 var last_selected;
  $("#service_id option").click(function(){
  if($(this).is(":selected")) {
   last_selected = $(this).attr('value');
  }  
 $("#result").html(last_selected);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="services[]" id="service_id" multiple>
  <option value="4">four</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

<p>Last selected : <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Comment: I need on change event

Comment: You cannot get last selected value in onChange event

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to get the last selected element?

Just create a variable to store the last selected element in each option click as shown by this demo:

```js
 var currLast = null;
 $('#service_id').children().on('click', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (currLast === val) { // do nothing if current selected is the same elem
      return;
    }
    currLast = val;
    console.log(currLast)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="services[]" id="service_id" multiple>
  <option value="4">four</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```